# Defining a class in Python

Tags: python, class, class-design

```
class Car:
    pass

class Car():
    pass
```

What is the difference between these two?
and,

```
a = Car

a = Car()
```

also, what is the difference between these two above?

Best Regards

Comment: Incidentally, you should usually inherit from `object` (eg. `class Car(object)`) to benefit from new-style classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the first statement, `a = Car` simply makes `a` an alias to `Car` class. So after you do that, you could do `b = a()` and it would be the same as `b = Car()`

Once you attach the `()` at the end, it makes python actually initialize the class (either `__call__` or just initialize, but you don't have to worry about that), and a becomes whatever 
that's returned by `Car()`, in this case, it is the class instance.

As for the difference between `class Car:` and `class Car():`. The second one is invalid syntax (edit: before 2.5, I would still say it's kind of bad style as there's no reason for it to be there if you're not inheritting). The reason you have the brackets there is when you need to inherit another class.

Comment: The second one has not been invalid syntax since 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, the latter is invalid syntax in older versions of Python.

In the second snippet, the former binds a reference to the class, and the latter binds a reference to a new instance of the class.